# C# Object Make the Values of Attributes into json object

Tags: c#, json

I have a C# Object that I need its attribute values into its own json object.  I'm struggling with how to do this dynamically.  I have attributes in my C# class that have values and I need to make those attribute values the Key/Value pair in the json respectively.

```
public class TransHelper
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Translation { get; set; }
}
TransHelper j = new TransHelper { Key = "MyKeyValue", 
                                  Translation = "MyTranslationValue" }; 
// Need to be json like this
// json { MyKeyValue: MyTranslationValue }
```

How do I make the attribute values get inserted into a new object where j.Key value is the new Key and j.Translation is the new value?  I can use newtonsoft or any json libraries out there, I am sure there is something simple I am missing here.

Comment: Do you have a list of these key/value pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class TransHelper
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Translation { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var myList = new List<TransHelper> {
        new TransHelper { Key = "K1", Translation = "T1" },
        new TransHelper { Key = "K2", Translation = "T2" },
        new TransHelper { Key = "K3", Translation = "T3" }
    };

    var dict = myList.ToDictionary(t => t.Key, t => t.Translation);
    //Serialize dict to Json using Newtonsoft.Json (JSON.Net) or Utf8Json libraries
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this one! Simple and clean.  Marking it as accepted answer for ToDictionary<> implementation.

Comment: If you want to simplify it even more, you can just get rid of the TransHelper entirely and simply use a dictionary's Key=Key and Value=Translation

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do such thing is by implementing a custom `JsonConverter` ([doc](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)).

There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base) on SO that can give more details on how to do it.

Here is one way to do this:

```
public class TransHelperConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var transHelperInst = value as TransHelper;

        if(transHelperInst is null)
             throw new ArgumentException();

        //  Creates the Json property. 
            var property = new JProperty(transHelperInst.Key, transHelperInst.Translation);

        //  Adds it the Json object.
        var transHelperObject = new JObject();
        transHelperObject.AddFirst(property);

        //  Writes the object.
        transHelperObject.WriteTo(writer);
   }

   public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
   }

  public override bool CanRead => false;

  public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
  {
      return objectType == typeof(TransHelper);
  }
}
```

Now, you can use this converter like this:

```
var serializedValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new TransHelper {Key = "MyKeyValue", Translation = "MyTranslationValue"}, Formatting.Indented, new TransHelperConverter());
```

This will give you the following result:

```
{
  "MyKeyValue": "MyTranslationValue"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can implement the generic abstract [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) from Json.NET class to achieve this.

Here's the converter implementation:

```
public class MySerializer : JsonConverter<TransHelper>
{
    public override TransHelper ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, TransHelper existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, TransHelper value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if(value == null) return;
        writer.WritePropertyName(value.Key);
        writer.WriteValue(value.Translation);
    }
}
```

Here's how you call it:

```
var j = new TransHelper
{
    Key = "MyKeyValue",
    Translation = "MyTranslationValue"
};

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(j, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, new MySerializer());
```

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use containers like [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) with `<Key, Value>`, then you can use `Newtonsoft.Json` (better than `JavaScriptSerializer`), the code will look like this:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
```

example:

```
var foo = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foo.Add("key1", "value1");
foo.Add("key2", "value2");
foo.Add("key3", "value3");
foo.Add("key4", "value4");

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo));
// outputs { "key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3","key4":"value4"}
```

Comment: I agree. See my answer for implementation

Answer (score 1):

Here's a custom converter that should do the trick (assuming you're using Newtonsoft Json.Net):

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{

  public class TransHelper
  {
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Translation { get; set; }
  }

  public class MyBlob
  {
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public TransHelper Bar { get; set; }
  }

  public class TransHelperConverter : JsonConverter<TransHelper>
  {

    public override TransHelper ReadJson( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, TransHelper existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
      string key = null;
      string val = null;
      TransHelper instance = null;

      if ( reader.TokenType != JsonToken.Null )
      {
        if ( reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartObject )
          throw new JsonReaderException( $"Unexpected Token: ${reader.TokenType}" );

        if ( !reader.Read() )
          throw new JsonReaderException( $"Unexpected EOF in Json" );

        if ( reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject )
        {
          if ( reader.TokenType != JsonToken.PropertyName )
            throw new JsonReaderException( $"Unexpected Token: ${reader.TokenType}" );

          key = (string)reader.Value;
          if ( !reader.Read() )
            throw new JsonReaderException( $"Unexpected EOF in Json" );

          if ( reader.TokenType != JsonToken.String )
            throw new JsonReaderException( $"Unexpected Token: ${reader.TokenType}" );

          val = (string)reader.Value;
          if ( !reader.Read() )
            throw new JsonReaderException( "Unexpected EOF in Json" );

        }

        if ( reader.TokenType != JsonToken.EndObject )
          throw new JsonReaderException( $"Unexpected Token: ${reader.TokenType}" );

        instance = new TransHelper
        {
          Key = key,
          Translation = val,
        };

      }

      return instance;
    }

    public override void WriteJson( JsonWriter writer, TransHelper value, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {

      writer.WriteStartObject();
      writer.WritePropertyName( value.Key );
      writer.WriteValue( value.Translation );
      writer.WriteEndObject();

      return;

    }

  }

  class Program
  {

    static void Main( string[] argv )
    {
      string json = @"
{
  ""Foo"": ""foo-value"",
  ""Bar"": {
    ""source"": ""translated-value""
  },
}".Trim();

      TransHelperConverter converter = new TransHelperConverter();
      MyBlob deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyBlob>( json, converter );
      string reserialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( deserialized, Formatting.Indented, converter );

      return;
    }

  }

}
```